# import function from subdictionary

Tags: python, python-import

I like to import functions from another dictionary python file. For example,

A.py contains a function get_total(), and B.py can get this function if user 'from A import get_total'.

However, when A.py need to import numpy module and use numpy.sum() in get_total() function, B.py can't use get_total() function from A. cause error "NameError: name 'np' is not defined", what's happend?

A.py:

```
import numpy as np
def get_total(list):
    return np.sum(list)
```

B.py:

```
from A import get_total

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

b=get_total(a)

print(b)
```

Error:

```
      1 import numpy
----> 2 def get_total(list):
      3         return numpy.sum(list)
      4 
      5 c = [1,2,3,4,5]

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Comment: in function you have used `numpy` not `np`

Comment: even i use import numpy as np, same error, and i also import numpy as np in B.py, not work

Comment: That error message doesn't match the code - you appear to have edited your source code without restarting Python. Restart Python.

Answer (score -1):

You need to also import numpy to B.py:

```
import numpy as np
from A import get_total
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b=get_total(a)
print(b)
```

Edit: This is not needed as all the numpy computations happen in `A.py`, which has numpy imported.

Comment: i have been import, same error, dont know why

Comment: one doesn't need to import packages twice. If a function/class is defined in a python module then all it's prerequisite should be completed there not anywhere else